# Leaflet GeoJASON layer control not work in this script?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am using Leaflet library recently, i find it very easy to work and learn, the tutorials are very good with GeoJSON and Control Layers, but i not find one tutorial about the use of control layers with GeoJASON files, i write this script:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="leaflet-src.js"></script>


<script src="GeoJason/mpios.geojson"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="GeoJason/roads.geojson"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="GeoJason/city.geojson"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="GeoJason/towns.geojson"type="text/javascript"></script> 


<style>
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var map = L.map('map').setView([20.990584, -98.65644], 12);

    L.geoJson(mpios).addTo(map);
    L.geoJson(roads).addTo(map);
    L.geoJson(city).addTo(map);
    L.geoJson(towns).addTo(map);


var baseLayers = {
    "roads": roads,
        "mpios": mpios
};


var overlays = {
       "city": city,
        "towns": towns
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

but it display the layers and the control buttons not work, thx.

Answer (score 2):

The layer values you are setting in your baseLayers and overlays is your geoJSON feature sets, but they should be leaflet layers or references to layers that exists on your map.

You can store the layer refernece for each of your geoJSON layers by setting the return value from L.geoJson to a variable like this:

```
var mpios_l = L.geoJson(mpios).addTo(map);
var roads_l = L.geoJson(roads).addTo(map);
var city_l = L.geoJson(city).addTo(map);
var towns_l = L.geoJson(towns).addTo(map);
```

Then add these items to your control.

```
var baseLayers = {
    "roads": roads_l,
        "mpios": mpios_l
};


var overlays = {
       "city": city_l,
        "towns": towns_l
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```